# Silverlight RIA Services with different database providers

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I want to create a Rich Internet Application in Silverlight. One of the requirements is that the back-end of the application should work with different database providers (SQLServer, PostgreSQL, Oracle). 
I'm planning to use Entity Data Model to represent database objects and Domain Services to expose these objects to the client.
The problem is that I don't have a clue if the same data model can be used with different database providers and how sophisticated that would be to change the provider without recreating all the model.
I want the application to be reusable on different environments, so that i can import the same database schema to any existing database, change the provider in the ASP.NET web application and that's it.
Is it doable? Or maybe there are other ways to achieve similar functionality? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would like advising you to look through existing [Entity Framework Best Practices](http://www.bing.com/search?q=entity+framework+best+practise&form=QBRE&qs=n&sk=)